# PHP CodeIgniter exception handling

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I am working on a system where every thing works fine as long as data is present in the database. But I wanted to test it against empty database. When I did that I got similar issues on almost every page.

> An uncaught Exception was encounteredType: ErrorMessage: Call to a
>   member function row() on boolean

I know what is issue here, but I want to know how I should handle the exception. I don't want the error message to disturb my system in case of empty database. One solution is turning off `error_reporting` but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: use isset or !empty on your result variable. and if it is not get any data do not use row(). else do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are sure there is one row for your query :

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1'";
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);

   if($query->num_rows() == 1)
   {
       $row = $query->row();
   }
   ```

2.If the result may contain multiple rows :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$query = $this->db->query($sql)->result();

if(!empty($query))
{
   foreach($query as $row)
    {
      //do something
    }
 }
```

`isset` will throw warning if the variable does not exist. `empty()` will not throw that warning